# UserManager FindAsync method calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The new ASP.NET MVC 5 Project-template generates a prepared `AccountController` including a base implementation of the `UserManager` and the underlying Stores (`IUserStore`, `IRoleStore` etc.).

This tutorial shows how to implement your custom UserStore for storing the user data in your custom data source: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider

However, I implemented my own `UserStore` and recognized the following:

During the login-process, a call to the `UserManager.FindAsync(UserName, Password)`-method inside the `AccountController` is made:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        **var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);**
        //other code
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The `FindAsync`-method calls the underlying `UserStore`-methods in the following order: `FindByNameAsync` -> `GetPasswordHashAsync` -> `FindByIdAsync`.

My question is: why are both, the `FindByNameAsync`- and `FindByIdAsync`-methods called? This results in 2 queries to the database, which affects the performance.

Comment: The FindAsync(string username, string password) method in UserManager doesn't call the FindByIdAsync, which makes this call is this line  var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); in the SignInAsyn method of AccountController

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

When your UserStore fetches your user with FindByNameAsync() it just finds and validates the user's existense.

When you fetch user info you wouldn't return the password to the application so this is why GetPasswordHashAsync() method is calling the database again to fetch your user's password hash.